# "Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2': not supported by any plugin"

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, modem, lte

I just bought a new laptop, HP EliteBook 840 G2. I used this computer during my travel in a train. I bought this laptop, because it has a 4G modem integrated. This modem works on Windows, but I can't use it on Linux.

I did what was explained in the [doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gobi_Broadband_Modems).

`lsusb` found the module :

```
Bus 002 Device 027: ID 03f0:8e1d Hewlett-Packard
```

When I tried to setup the modem with

```
systemctl status ModemManager
```

it showed me this error:

```
Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2': not supported by any plugin
```

How I can setup my modem on ArchLinux ?

Comment: Did you install gobi-loader and load the module?

Comment: Exactly up to what part of the guide you followed?

Comment: yes I use this command to load the module "modprobe qcserial vendor=0x03f0 product=0x8e1d"

Comment: HP, Lenovo, Dell, Toshiba and Compaq are know for giving often other IDs to modem/wireless cards, and whitelisting them in the ROM in order not to allow you to exchange them. I once had a mini HP for travelling, same problems using it as an hackintosh, never again.